# What is the name of this segment on UIMenuItem?

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller

[image: UIMenuItem]

I know that the `UIMenuController` can show a popover containing Cut, Copy, Paste, Select/All, and other system menu items.  But I don't know what the last item is, visible in the screenshot above.  What is its function?  Does it call anything within the application, and if so, what?  Can it be disabled?  In this case, I would like to disable or remove the item programmatically, without disabling any international keyboards.

Comment: Looks like that's just a right-to-left writing toggle.  You can probably disable it if you disable whichever international keyboard is using it.  Also, not really sure this is the right place to ask this question, since I don't think it's really programming related?

Comment: sorry, i have update my question. I just want to remove that segment, but i still can use some international keyboard like Arabic and Hebrew, but without change that direction, can i??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about disabling the RTL menu item programmatically without disabling international keyboards, it doesn't appear that you can - at least not while using `UIMenuController.`  If you look at the documentation for its `menuItems` property, it explains that custom items can be inserted after system items, but makes no indication that you can remove those system items that you for some reason do not want.

Tapping it might result in iOS calling the `UITextInput` protocol's `setBaseWritingDirection:forRange:` method.  I don't know about that, though – I can only guess since there's no clear explanation of this that I'm aware of after a short run around the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

That right-most "arrow" `UIMenuItem` pictured is indeed a system item. The selector for it is called `_setRtoLTextDirection`: or `_setLtoRTextDirection`: I suspect apple wouldn't want you messing with them as the auto-complete in Xcode doesn't help you when you try to type these methods.

To disable them, check for them and return "NO" in your overridden - `(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender` method.

For anyone else that wants to disable the default `UIMenuItems` in the `UIMenuItemController`, you can find the complete list (or most of them at least) in my [blog](http://tylermilner.com/?p=316).